# symfony2 This web page has a redirect loop

Tags: php, symfony

I am building a Symfony2 project but I have a problem: I configured the **security.yml** and **routing.yml** to create an authentication system. I have 2 bundles: one for admin and one for users. When I try to access to the login page I have a redirect loop.

This is my **security.yml** file :

```yaml
security:
    encoders:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
                algorithm: bcrypt
                cost: 12
            BackOfficeBundle\Entity\Administrateur:
                 algorithm: bcrypt
            BackOfficeBundle\Entity\Collaborateur:
                 algorithm: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    providers:
            administrators:
                entity: { class: BackOfficeBundle:Administrateur, property: username }
            users:
                entity: { class: BackOfficeBundle:Collaborateur, property: email }


    firewalls:
            dev:
                pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                security: false

            front_login:
                pattern:   ^/login$
                anonymous: true
            back_login:
                pattern:   ^/login$
                anonymous: true
            back:
                pattern:   ^/platform
                anonymous: true
                provider: administrators

                form_login:
                    login_path: /platform/login
                    check_path: /platform/login_check
                    default_target_path: /platform

                logout:
                    path:   /platform/logout
                    target: /platform/login

            front:
                pattern:   ^/collaborateur
                anonymous: false
                provider: users
                form_login:
                    login_path: /collaborateur/login
                    check_path: /collaborateur/login_check
                    default_target_path: /collaborateur

                logout:
                    path:   /collaborateur/logout
                    target: /collaborateur/clogin


    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
         - { path: ^/platform, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/collaborateur, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

And this is the **app/config/routing.yml**:

```yaml
front_office:
    resource: "@FrontOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /collaborateur

back_office:
    resource: "@BackOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /platform
```

and the **BackOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml**:

```yaml
login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: UserBundle:Security:login }

login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check

logout:
    pattern:   /logout
```

Comment: any solution to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to describe in the `security.yml` that the login route are public as follow:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/platform/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/collaborateur/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/platform, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/collaborateur, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Hope this help

Comment: the login route is already defined as public with   :  back_login:
                pattern:   ^/login$
                anonymous: true

Comment: you don't need the front_login and back_login firewall. Can you find in which page the redirect loop is closed?

Comment: no i can't but it happen when i try to access to http://localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/platform/login

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
firewalls:
    ...    

    front_login:
        pattern:   ^/platform/login$
        anonymous: true

    back_login:
       pattern:   ^/collaborateur/login$
       anonymous: true

    ...
```

Your login form is on `/platform/login` but your anonymous security exceptions are only for `/login` (which is wrong) and everything under `^/platform` is protected. Symfony detects secured area and try to redirect to login path but `/platform/login` is again in secured area (and again, again, again).